# Crystal visualization software for visualizing lattice with reciprocal vectors drawn in same image

Tags: solid-state-physics, software, crystals, visualization

I'm looking for a free crystal visualization program, preferably for Linux, that can visualize the common lattice structures in 3D interactively (rotatable with mouse) and draw in the same picture the axes of the direct lattice base vectors.
It would be nice if it could also draw the reciprocal lattice and Brillouin zones and Wigner-Seitz cells on top of that.

Most importantly, I'd like to have the axes in the same image. The background for this is that I want to easily visualize if my text book says something like "this is the case for NaCl in the [111] direction".

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this program and have never used it, but it seems promising: [VESTA](http://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "molekel"
http://molekel.cscs.ch/wiki/pmwiki.php 
or "jmol" 
http://jmol.sourceforge.net/ 
Best regards 
Jose Luis